# Subcategories and Categories in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, conventions

What is the correct convention for making categories and subcategories in CakePHP?

Do you make two database table? Two models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends on what you want to build in the longer run. If you want to have a one table setup, then checking out the [tree behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1339/Tree) could be worthy.
But if your requirements analysis turns out that categories and subcategories differ substantially, you are better off with a two table (and two models) setup imho.